# soft constraints not working properly for a bit variable

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

I have a variable `data` where I want the last bit to be 1 and the rest of the bits to be 0, and I have written this using `soft` `constraint`.

```
class ABC;
  rand bit [3:0] data;
 
  // This constraint is defined as "soft" 
  constraint c_data {
                       soft data == 0;
                            data[0] == 1;
                    }
endclass
 
module tb;
  ABC abc;

  initial begin
    abc = new;
    abc.randomize();
    $display ("data = %0b", abc.data);
  end
endmodule
```

I expect the output to be 'b0001, but the actual output is `data` = 'b1101

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is caused by the way you define your soft constraint `soft data == 0`.

Soft contraints will only be satisfied if they don't contradict other (hard) constraints. Your soft constraint says that *all* bits of `data[3:0]` must be `0`. In your hard constraint, however, you say that `data[0]` must be `1`. Consequently, the soft constraint cannot be satisfied and is ignored.

You can verify this by defining `data == 0` as a hard constraint: The randomization will then fail.

To get the behaviour you expect, try to define the class as follows:

```
class ABC;
    rand bit [3:0] data;

    // This constraint is defined as "soft" 
    constraint c_data {
                        soft data[3:1] == 0;
                        data[0]        == 1;
                       }
endclass
```